# How does javascript function scope work with arguments?

Tags: javascript, scope, arguments

What doesn't the 2nd console.log below return 2? Is it because inside the function scope when I assign `thing = thing + 1`, the assignment of `thing` is just another variable? It's no longer referring to the original `thing` argument that was passed in?

```
function change(thing) {
  thing = thing + 1;
  return thing;
}

let a = 1

console.log(change(a)) //2
console.log(a)         //1
```

Comment: The function doesn't change the value of `a`.  So `a` is still 1.

Comment: Basically than answer is yes...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 1):

That's because in javascript when you pass primitive types to  a function like "string" or "number" only a copy is passed, if it were an object or an array then the value would change because those types are passed by reference, for example:

```js
function change(thing) {
  thing.value = thing.value + 1;
  return thing;
}

let a = {value: 1};

console.log(change(a)) 
console.log(a)
```

Comment: **1.** Even if an object or array is passed to to `change`, the variable `a` won't be changed, at least not in the way OP is trying to change it. **2.** There is no such thing as pass by reference in javascript. Objects are passed around by a reference to them instead of their value, but the variables aren't passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript always **pass by value** so changing the value of the variable never changes the underlying primitive (**String or number**).

Pass by Reference happens only for objects. In Pass by Reference, Function is called by directly passing the reference/address of the variable as the argument. Changing the argument inside the function affect the variable passed from outside the function. In Javascript objects and arrays follows pass by reference.

```
function callByReference(varObj) { 
  console.log("Inside Call by Reference Method"); 
  varObj.a = 100; 
  console.log(varObj); 
} 
let varObj = {a:1};
console.log("Before Call by Reference Method"); 
console.log(varObj);
callByReference(varObj) 
console.log("After Call by Reference Method"); 
console.log(varObj);
```

### Output will be :

Before Call by Reference Method

{a: 1}

Inside Call by Reference Method

{a: 100}

After Call by Reference Method

{a: 100}